# Set Operations(or Logical Operations) and the Redundancy of Parentheses Surrounding Them

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When can parentheses be simplified or omitted in set expressions?
I'm working on the following set expression and want to confirm if my expansion is correct or if I should have simplified it differently. I would appreciate your input along with reasons.

Given the expression:
**A'∩((A ∩ B') ∪ (A' ∩ B))**

I expanded it as follows:

[Here, 'u' represents the universal set, and ' is used to denote complement]

A'∩((A ∩ B') ∪ (A' ∩ B))

=A'∩((A ∪ (A' ∩ B) ∩ B'∪ (A' ∩ B)))

=A'∩(A∪A' ∩ A∪B ∩ B'∪A ∩ B'∪B)

=A'∩(u ∩ A∪B ∩ B'∪A ∩ u)

=A'∩( A∪B ∩ B'∪A)

=A'∩(A∪(B∩B'))

=A'∩(A∪(Φ))

=Φ

**I opened the brackets around ∪ instead of just applying A'∩ to both terms, in both these ways I am getting different answers which shouldn't be the case.**

Please provide your feedback and reasons for where I went wrong. Thank you

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am looking for an answer instead of comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of using Logical Operation/Set Operation and the Redundancy of Parentheses Surrounding Them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799401/order-of-using-logical-operation-set-operation-and-the-redundancy-of-parentheses)